# R Concatenate column names into new column while sorting by their value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I'm trying to concatenate a string that identifies the order of the columns by their value.

```
set.seed(100)

df <- tibble(id = 1:5,
             col1 = sample(1:50, 5),
             col2 = sample(1:50, 5),
             col3 = sample(1:50, 5)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-id), ~if_else(. <= 20, NA_integer_, .))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
     id  col1  col2  col3
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA    44    NA
2     2    38    23    34
3     3    48    22    NA
4     4    25    NA    48
5     5    NA    NA    43

res <- df %>% 
  add_column(order = c('col2',
                       'col2_col3_co1',
                       'col2_col1',
                       'col1_col3',
                       'col3'))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
     id  col1  col2  col3 order        
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>        
1     1    NA    44    NA col2         
2     2    38    23    34 col2_col3_co1
3     3    48    22    NA col2_col1    
4     4    25    NA    48 col1_col3    
5     5    NA    NA    43 col3
```

My current data is in the form of df while the column I'm trying to add is the order column in res. The ordering of the elements in the string is determined by the value of each column, and it also needs to skip over NAs. I'm trying to identify the sequence that each ID takes to populate a value in each column as the values are time in days. However, not all IDs will have a value in all columns, so there's missing values throughout. I usually work within tidyverse, but any solution or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option  is `apply`, loop over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`), remove the  `NA` elements, `order` the rest of the non-NA, use the index to get the column names and `paste` them together

```
df$order <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {x1 <- x[!is.na(x)]
           paste(names(x1)[order(x1)], collapse="_")})
df$order
#[1] "col2"           "col2_col3_col1" "col2_col1"      "col1_col3"      "col3"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   arrange(id,  value) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(order = str_c(name, collapse="_")) %>% 
   right_join(df) %>%
   select(names(df), order)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#     id  col1  col2  col3 order         
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>         
#1     1    NA    44    NA col2          
#2     2    38    23    34 col2_col3_col1
#3     3    48    22    NA col2_col1     
#4     4    25    NA    48 col1_col3     
#5     5    NA    NA    43 col3
```

---

Or using `pmap` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(order = pmap_chr(select(., starts_with('col')), ~
         {x <- c(...)
         x1 <- x[!is.na(x)]
         str_c(names(x1)[order(x1)], collapse="_")}))
```

Comment: This doesn't handle `NA` correctly, it returns 1 for the first row. try `names(x)[order(x, na.last = NA)]`

Comment: @astrofunkswag yes, thanks, I had a typo. corrected

Comment: Thank you for the multiple solutions. The apply approach is certainly more straightforward which isn't surprising as rowwise operations tend to seem more complicated than they should be with the tidyverse. I figured that purrr::pmap would be able to accomplish this well, so thank you for the example.